# How do I call a jquery code from code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Right now i'm hiding div elements with this script

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

            $('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').hide();
            $('#<%=phaseTwo.ClientID%>').hide();
            $('#<%=phaseThree.ClientID%>').hide();
});
```

And I wanted it to show with a `$('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').show();` code for an example upon triggering a button that is base on a logic and status from the database

Comment: You can send a ajax call to on receiving the response show the elements you want.

Comment: I can't, I'm having trouble with ajax (Ajax Control Toolkit) and thus this was the only alternative way I could think of.  I've been hit with this error message if i tried to:  "RegisterDataItem can only be called during an async postback."

Comment: If it is just for one time when page load then you can hide these controls from server. Other wise you can show hide using postback on server side instead of javascript

Comment: I've tried that, it won't work.  Refer to my error that I have encountered [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555879/why-does-hiding-a-div-that-has-an-ajax-popupcontrolextender-for-calendar-in-pa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can call the javascript fucntion as shown below

in the C# code you can call the following code on completion of condition

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "key", "Display()", true);
```

and in the .aspx page you can have your div and function mentioned as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function Display() {            
            var e = document.getElementById('<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>');         
            if (e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
            else
                e.style.display = 'block';
            return false;
        }
 </script>

<div id="phaseOne" style="display: none;position:absolute;  
    top:300px;
    right:250px;  "</div>
```

Comment: @user3195396 css you have to take care by trying yourself

Comment: Ok fixed, I just put `inline-block` instead of `block`.  Thanks, also what does `key` mean?

Comment: key is just the inique identifier for the script block as ScriptManagercan hold many scripts , in that case it nees to identify each script with some key

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
   HideAll();
}
 function HideAll() 
{   
  $('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').hide();
  $('#<%=phaseTwo.ClientID%>').hide();
  $('#<%=phaseThree.ClientID%>').hide();
}

function ShowPhase1()
{
  $('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').show();
}

</script>
```

- Use `GetType()` instead of `typeof(Page)` in order to bind the script to your actual page class instead of the base class
- Pass a key constant instead of `Page.UniqueID`, which is not that meaningful since it's supposed to be used by named controls,
- End your Javascript statement with a `semicolon`

In Code Behind on `Button Click`:

```
if(somecondition==true)
{
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "key", "ShowPhase1();", true);
}
```

Add as much as function to `show/hide` and call from codebehind.

Comment: what does `key` means?  Do I have to use the same 'key' for all the Scriptmanager?

Comment: use function as it is just change the function name from "ShowPhase1()' to yourfunction() name that set..! please check the edit!

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

`$(document).ready(function () {
<% if (someservervalue == true)
{ %>
$('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').show();
<% } else { %>
$('#<%=phaseOne.ClientID%>').hide();
<% } %>
$('#<%=phaseTwo.ClientID%>').hide();
$('#<%=phaseThree.ClientID%>').hide(); });`

Another way would be to use Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock. More info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)